# How to get relative file path of app.settings file shared between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, filepath, appsettings

I have an appsettings.config file in the root of my solution, displayed in the 'Solution Items' folder that I want to reference in 3 different projects

[image]

These 3 projects consist of the following

- Web performance and load test project
- Unit test project (UI automation tests)
- Standard Class Library

I have a static wrapper for the config file in the class library project that I intend to reference from the other projects.

The problem I have is getting the correct relative path of the solution root directory, regardless of which project is running at the time.

This is my code for the wrapper class....

```
public static class TestConfiguration
{
    private static Configuration Config { get; }

    static TestConfiguration()
    {
        var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();

        map.ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(@"../../../appsettings.config");

        Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    }

    public static string SepaTestDb {
        get { return Config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["SEPATest"].ConnectionString; }
    }

    public static string ApiUrl => Config.AppSettings.Settings["apiUrl"].Value;
}
```

This works for the load test project but for the others I get...

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium.Integration
```

...when I try to get either the SepaTestDb or the ApiUrl property, presumably due to the object not being initialized from an invalid file path

How do I set a relative path so that the appsettings.config file is accessible from the different projects, and will be picked up if any of the projects are being run in a build/in the cloud etc.

**EDIT**

..and this is my appsettings.config file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SEPATest" connectionString="Server=[server];Database=SEPA-c7455a3a-86bd-4862-bb25-2b5d17d97f95Test;User Id=[username];Password=[password];" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="apiUrl" value="https://sasepaapi-sasepaapitest.azurewebsites.net/api" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Many thanks,

Comment: `Solution Items` isn't a physical folder. It's a virtual folder inside of VS.

Comment: @KennethK. I believe in stating 'correct relative path of the solution root directory' I indicated I was aware of this.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:** Mostly for development, it won't allow sharing config file on running environment

You can **link** appsettings.config to each project (Add Item As Link)

Then change "Copy To Output Directory" Property of these links to "Copy If Newer"

[image]

In the config file of each project use below:

```
...    
<appSettings configSource="appsettings.config" />
...
```

**UPDATE :**

**Solution 2:** Support sharing config file on running environment

For hosting the appsettings.config at a common place
You can also use this in projects's config files:

```
...
<appSettings file=".\..\..\..\appsettings.config" />
...
```

Or

An absolute path

```
...
<appSettings file="C:\tmp\appsettings.config" />
...
```

You can access these settings via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]. No extra work required for loading that file.

Comment: Hi Khoa, Unfortunately I couldn't get this working. Here is what I did: 1. Removed all the appsettings.config files against each individual project (I was duplicating them), 2. On each project I did add existing item, add as link, referencing the appsettings.config at the solution root directory. 3. In the properties for each link I changed 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Copy if newer. 4. I added configSource="appsettings.config" to both the <appSettings> section and the <connectionStrings> section. 5. I ran the unit test project and got an object reference error as the contents were null.

Comment: Hmm, it works pretty well for me. Do you have an App.config file for UnitTest project ? Visual Studio won't copy App.config of tested projects to UnitTest's project output. UnitTest project needs to have its own App.config file.

Comment: "How do I set a relative path so that the appsettings.config file is accessible from the different projects, and will be picked up if any of the projects are being run in a build/in the cloud etc."  -> use Solution 2 then